# Is Host header poisoning possible in such case?

Tags: django, security, nginx, pyramid, webob

Django team considers host header poisoning (CVE-2011-4139 and CVE-2012-4520) as a security issue that must be resolved at a framework level. Pyramid, for instance (that is, its underlying low-level request wrapper—webob) does not consider this as an issue.

On production & development machines I have nginx which seems to pass correct `SERVER_NAME` even if `Host` header contains complete garbage, and responds with [444 No response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#444) if there is no matching [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name).

Question: should I worry about `Host` header poisoning in such case, if I use `SERVER_NAME` to build absolute URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use nginx to sanitize the HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME fields, you are doing the right thing and do not need to worry about Host header poisining.

Like Django, Pyramid considers a large part of this the task of the WSGI host environment. And nginx does an excellent, battle-hardened job of sanitizing the HTTP request information.

Comment: I‘d say, “Django considers this as the task of itself at some extent” :)

Comment: @ASKSBADQUESTIONS: see [the CVE-2012-4520 advisory](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/oct/17/security/): *Some attacks against this are beyond Django's ability to control, and require the web server to be properly configured*.

Comment: That‘s why it shouldn‘t be Django‘s problem. It is bad configuration, not framework (maybe Django developers have their own opinion on this, who knows). P.S. I mentioned that CVE in question ;) Plus, I saw (somewhere, do not remember where) bad fix-security-of-other-project changes that made code a) hard to read & change b) insecure. What do you think?